# bash: defining a file-local variable invisible to sourcing script

Tags: bash

Say I have a bash script file `config.sh`. It's meant to be source'd by other scripts and variables defined is used as customization of the upper-level scripts.

The problem is, if `config.sh` has a temporary variable and its name conflicts with upper-level scripts' variable, it breaks the upper-level one.

config.sh:

```
TMP1=abc
CONFIG_INPUT_DIR="$TMP1"/in
CONFIG_OUTPUT_DIR="$TMP1"/out
```

upper-level script:

```
TMP1=def
source config.sh
echo $TMP1
```

The last `echo` prints `abc`, not `def`.

## Solution 1

My current solution is to append a random string to the temporary variable name to make it almost impossible to conflict. e.g:

```
TMP1_vFc9Uiew=abc
CONFIG_INPUT_DIR="$TMP1_vFc9Uiew"/in
CONFIG_OUTPUT_DIR="$TMP1_vFc9Uiew"/out
unset TMP1_vFc9Uiew
```

which is painful and makes the code hard to read, in addition not to be perfect.

## Solution 2 using `local` keyword

After some searching, I've come to know `local` keyword.
But when I simply declare `TMP1` as `local`, bash complains that `config.sh: line 1: local: can only be used in a function`.

So my another solution is to enclose whole config script as a function:

```
function config_func_rZ0Yqkpm() {
  local TMP1=abc
  CONFIG_INPUT_DIR="$TMP1"/in
  CONFIG_OUTPUT_DIR="$TMP1"/out
}
config_func_rZ0Yqkpm
unset config_func_rZ0Yqkpm
```

which is better than previous solution in maintainability and readability, but there's some possibility to conflict as well as solution 1.

## Question

I want to know more robust and smart solution without any possibility to conflict.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A trick I learned from the [`keychain`](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Keychain) utility is using one program to build a `source`-able file containing just the variables that you want to export from your program. You could modify your script to `echo` the variables you want to set and then source the *output* from your program:

```
$ echo $FOO

$ source <(echo FOO=bar)
$ echo $FOO
bar
$
```

I used `echo FOO=bar` to simulate the larger script; your program is probably more involved. The important part is that you must modify your program to output the variables and values you would like to set, rather than just setting them. This lets you decide which variables to expose and which ones to hold private at the cost of another shell process.

Comment: `ssh-agent` uses a similar technique, with the `-c` and `-s` options.

Comment: @jjlin: Thank you! I thought `keychain` wasn't exactly the place I saw it first, but it was the first place I found the documentation. :) Funny, it's sitting right there in the open in the `ssh-agent` manpage...

Comment: AFAIK Using this technique requires the caller always to be aware of using the source command. Isn't there a technique which makes it possible to change the caller's environment variables without these inconveniences?

Answer (score 10):

You could avoid variables and use functions in config.sh to hold your values:

```
get_dirname() { echo "abc"; }
CONFIG_INPUT_DIR="$(get_dirname)/in"
CONFIG_OUTPUT_DIR="$(get_dirname)/out"
unset -f get_dirname
```

If you're still concerned about name collision for functions, this doesn't really help you.

Answer (score 8):

The "ssh-agent" method:

config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=abc
printf "CONFIG_INPUT_DIR=%s/in\n" "$TMP"
printf "CONFIG_OUTPUT_DIR=%s/out\n" "$TMP"
```

main program:

```
TMP1=def
eval "$(config.sh)"
echo "$TMP1"
```

Comment: You would put ";" at the end of each printf command so that eval commands are separated by ";".

Comment: What I should have done is quote the command substitution so that the newlines are preserved. Fixing that.